# context: singular/plural

Tags: grammatical-number

[1]
Before the development of TCGA, genomic science was performed by individual institutions using single genomic platforms.

[2]
Specific types of malignancies as well as individual tumors themselves have been characterized in detail.

in [1] and [2] should "individual institutions" and "individual tumors" be replaced with "individual institution" and "individual tumor"

Answer (score 1):

No, your examples are grammatically correct as written.